# Cannot deploy UWP app to raspberry pi 3

Tags: c#, uwp, raspberry-pi3, windows-10-iot-core

I'm getting an error :

> Error: Unable to connect to the Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugger named 'minwinpc'.  The Visual Studio 2017 Remote Debugger (MSVSMON.EXE) does not appear to be running on the remote computer. This may be because a firewall is preventing communication to the remote computer. Please see Help for assistance on configuring remote debugging.

I'm trying to deploy an app to my RPI 3 running Windows 10 IoT Core v.10.0.16299.15.

I've tried:

- Reinstalling Visual Studio 2017
- Installing Visual Studio 2017 Remote Debugger.
- Restarting the VS.

I noticed that Visual Studio 2015 remoter debugger is running on raspberry pi and it has 192.168.0.6:8116 as a remote machine name while in VS2017, rpi's address is 192.168.0.6:4002. Why are they different? Can someone help me?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](//superuser.com).

Comment: @FrankerZ all those Tools are used exclusively for programming, sounds perfectly on topic.

Answer (score 1):

As Martin & Belekz mentioned,you can check the configuration of target device and firewall setting.And more,I want to add that,please note the configuration of **[Authentication Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/deploying-and-debugging-uwp-apps#authentication-modes)**.You should set it as "***Universal(Unencrypted Protocol)***".Use the mode whenever you are deploying to a remote device. Currently, this is for IoT devices, Xbox devices, and HoloLens devices, as well as Creators Update or newer PCs.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Look at my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48320673/cannot-deploy-uwp-app-to-raspberry-pi-from-vs2017/48331897#48331897) i have the same problem and i tried several things, but only after i done this i can deploy remotely to pi again:

- Uninstall old 16299 SDK and download new 16299 SDK from [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk)
- Repair VS from VSInstaller
- run sfc /scannow

Also make sure you're using Universal authentication mode and type the ip without port number (or even using 'minwinpc' is enough)

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the remote debugger's IP address and port to point to the correct endpoint of your Remote debugger.

Right-click the UWP app project, choose `Properties`, and in `Debug` tab you will see `Start options` with **Target device** which should be set to **Remote Machine** and below you can manually enter the Remote debugger's IP address and port into the **Remote Machine** field (`192.168.0.6:8116` in your case). You **should include the 8116 port** in the **Remote Machine** field as well.

This should make Visual Studio connect to the Remote debugger instead of the RPI itself.

Also try to **turn off the firewall** to verify if it does not interfere with the connection.

Answer (score 0):

I never deployed software from VS to a RPi using an port in the IP address before. So maybe you are doing something special, or I'm doing something basic, but;

1. dubble check if you need to assign a port.
2. Start Windows 10 IoT Core Dashboard and check if the Pi is visible
   in your network.

   --> If not, try to ping to your Pi, using the CMD

   ```
   ping 192.168.0.6
   ```

   --> If the ping fails, check your IP address of your Pi with a physical
   monitor.
3. Check the address in the build properties according to the steps above.

   [image: printscreen properties]

Hope this helps!

Comment: I've done the 3 steps but I still can't deploy my app. I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Community.  The Remote debugger running in the Pi says Please use 192.168.0.6:8116 as remote machine name from Visual Studio 2015 to connect to the device. The Pi is auto-detected in VS but has the address of 192.168.0.6:4022

Comment: Are you connected with Wifi to your Pi or with a cable?

Comment: I am connected with wifi to the Pi

Comment: Try to connect using a wire. So build a point to point network with your Pi. Simple connect your laptop/desktop with 1 wire to the Pi. You should use another IP address now, so check the monitor again for the correct IP and try to establish an wired connection.

Answer (score 0):

i have see same problem in my laptop. i solve this problem by following steps..

first of all can you install  Windows 10 IOT SDK in your .net?

if no then first of all download and install.
otherwise update vs 2017.

when install vs 2017 then automatically install iot sdk.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on correlation of your answer to the question?