# Cannot deploy UWP app to raspberry pi from VS2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, remote-debugging, windows-10-iot-core

ok so i have the same problem as [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48296312/cannot-deploy-uwp-app-to-raspberry-pi-3), im trying to deploy an UWP app with VS2017 15.5.4 to Raspberry pi 3 using my PC but getting this error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: SerialSample, Configuration: Debug ARM   ------
1>C:\Users\sco1o\OneDrive\Skripsi\Research\SerialUART\CS\MainPage.xaml.cs(220,42,220,45): warning CS0168: The variable 'tce' is declared but never used
1>  SerialSample -> C:\Users\sco1o\OneDrive\Skripsi\Research\SerialUART\CS\bin\ARM\Debug\SerialSample.exe
2>------ Deploy started: Project: SerialSample, Configuration: Debug ARM ------
2>DEP6100: The following unexpected error occurred during bootstrapping stage 'Connecting to the device '192.168.1.10'.': FileNotFoundException - Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Tools.Connectivity, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. [0x80070002]
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

- My [Debug Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6WPL.png)
- My Target Build is 16299 and Min 15063
- My PC running Windows 10 Pro 16299
- My Raspberry Pi build 16299.192, connected to a LAN switch, im able to open device portal, ping showing no problem
- Tried turning off windows firewall and defender
- Checked Enable Windows IoT Remote Server on portal
- Tried Start/Stopping vs remote debugger manually with/without default account on portal
- Tried changing target remote machine address box to 192.168.1.10, 192.168.1.10:8116, minwinpc, MINWINPC
- Tried 3 times reinstalling VS, first 2 using cmd line, the last is using vs installer
- I tried restarting my pc and pi several times
- tried changing Universal auth to Windows and None, no luck
- tried 2 times reinstalling windows IoT and updating it on pi

**HOWEVER**, my laptop can deploy easily to my pi without error....

ps. this issue started 2 days ago when i tried reinstalling my VS on PC, i have no issue like this before that

Comment: Looks like a problem with Windows 10 SDK. Make sure it is properly installed. And maybe reinstall it.

Comment: i tried repairing 16299 and 15063 SDK from Apps & Features but still no luck... im now downloading 16299 SDK from [this link](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is now resolved, here's what i do:

- Uninstall old 16299 SDK and download new 16299 SDK
- Repair VS from VSInstaller
- run sfc /scannow, there's some corrupted system files but now is restored.

Thank you Fabian for your help